# Does there exists a name for this type of relation among subsets of a poset?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

The question is,

> Let $(P,\le)$ be a poset and $S,T\subseteq P$ such that the following holds, $$\forall t\forall s(t\in T\land s\in S\to s\le t)$$does this type of relation between $S$ and $T$ has a standard name?

I thought about phrasing the property as saying that "each element of $T$ dominates $S$". But it would surely be good if there is a standrad terminology (and if possible some standard notation as well) for it.

Comment: If you're written $s\lt t$ instead of $s\le t$ the notation $S\lt T$ is pretty standard, I think.  I guess your relation could be written $S\le T$ but it doesn't offhand seem that it would be as useful as the relation $S\lt T$.

Comment: At the very least, when T is a singleton $\{t\}$, I have seen people say $t$ dominates $S$, so if there is a standard nomenclature, you might have guessed it

Comment: @bof: Does the relation $S<T$ has any standard name?

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is the set of lower bounds of $T$,
$T$ is the set of upper bounds of $S$.

It is a generalization of a Dedekind cut.